# YUI error: Uncaught ReferenceError: YUI is not defined

Tags: yui, yahoo-api

I am a jQuery user and just learning YUI.  I have the following code and I keep the error that YUI is not defined.  I know it is an issue with linking to the library but I'm not exactly sure what. I had someone else test my code where they had YUI held locally and it worked fine.  If I need to do this, how do I obtain a copy of the min.js file? When you download a copy from the YUI site its a tonne of files...

```
<head>
    <title>YUI3 Test</title
     <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <p>Click here to test.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        YUI().use('node', 'event', function (Y){
            var changeText = function(e){
                e.target.setHTML("<p>Now you see the test working.</p>");
            }

            var node = Y.one("#menu");
            node.on("click", changeText);

            //node.on("click", function(e){
            //    Y.one(node).load('menu.html');
            //});
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified the script file is indeed loading?  The very first line in the file is `var YUI=function()` so it's tough to believe you'd get an error saying `YUI is undefined` unless the file wasn't loaded.

Comment: The [script](http://jsfiddle.net/jgdx/YSNcd/) works beautifully.

If you are using HTML 4.1, the `type` attribute is required. Normally all browsers will assume it is `text/javascript`, but maybe, in your case, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `>` after `</title`. This may be causing the script tag not to be recognized and so it's not loading.

Here it is broken: http://jsbin.com/ubaxoy/1/edit

And here it works after adding the missing `>`: http://jsbin.com/ubaxoy/2/edit

I also had to change `setHTML` to `setContent` because YUI 3.2 didn't have `setHTML` yet. I'd also recommend you to use a newer version of YUI, from 3.9.1 up. There have been a number of great additions since 3.2.